# Measuring processor ticks in C

Tags: c, benchmarking, clock

I wanted to calculate the difference in execution time when executing the same code inside a function. To my surprise, however, sometimes the clock difference is 0 when I use clock()/clock_t for the start and stop timer. Does this mean that clock()/clock_t does not actually return the *number of clicks* the processor spent on the task?

After a bit of searching, it seemed to me that clock_gettime() would return more fine grained results. And indeed it does, but I instead end up with an abitrary number of nano(?)seconds. It gives a hint of the difference in execution time, but it's hardly accurate as to exactly how many clicks difference it amounts to. What would I have to do to find this out?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define M_PI_DOUBLE (M_PI * 2)

void rotatetest(const float *x, const float *c, float *result) {
    float rotationfraction = *x / *c;
    *result = M_PI_DOUBLE * rotationfraction;
}

int main() {

    int i;
    long test_total = 0;
    int test_count = 1000000;
    struct timespec test_time_begin;
    struct timespec test_time_end;

    float r = 50.f;
    float c = 2 * M_PI * r;
    float x = 3.f;
    float result_inline = 0.f;
    float result_function = 0.f;

    for (i = 0; i < test_count; i++) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &test_time_begin);
        float rotationfraction = x / c;
        result_inline = M_PI_DOUBLE * rotationfraction;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &test_time_end);
        test_total += test_time_end.tv_nsec - test_time_begin.tv_nsec;
    }

    printf("Inline clocks %li, avg %f (result is %f)\n", test_total, test_total / (float)test_count,result_inline);

    for (i = 0; i < test_count; i++) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &test_time_begin);
        rotatetest(&x, &c, &result_function);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &test_time_end);
        test_total += test_time_end.tv_nsec - test_time_begin.tv_nsec;
    }

    printf("Function clocks %li, avg %f (result is %f)\n", test_total, test_total / (float)test_count, result_inline);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using **gcc version 4.8.4** on **Linux 3.13.0-37-generic** (Linux Mint 16)

Comment: You need to tell us which OS / which compiler you are using (GCC/Linux ?).

Comment: A difference of a few nanoseconds is not significative, maybe you could call your function a large number of times (1 million) and measure the differences of timings.

Comment: I think I actually do already, @BrunoLevy. I added the details, though, thanks.

Comment: I was not clear enough, was I meant is moving the calls to clock_gettime() outside the loop.

Comment: what compiler options did you use ? If you used -O, it is possible that the compiler decided to inline the function call (this may explain why you got the same timings).

Comment: Nope, just gcc -Wall -g -o "functionoverhead" "functionoverhead.c" -lm-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: As already mentioned in the comments, clocking a single run of execution one by the other will probably do you no good. If all goes down the hill, the call for getting the time might actually take longer than the actual execution of the operation.

Please clock multiple runs of the operation (including a warm up phase so everything is swapped in) and calculate the average running times.

`clock()` isn't guaranteed to be monotonic. It also isn't the number of *processor clicks* (whatever you define this to be) the program has run. The best way to describe the result from `clock()` is probably "*a best effort estimation of the time any one of the CPUs has spent on calculation for the current process*". For benchmarking  purposes `clock()` is thus mostly useless.

As [per specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock.html):

> The `clock()` function returns the implementation's best approximation to the processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-dependent time related only to the process invocation.

And additionally

> To determine the time in seconds, the value returned by clock() should be divided by the value of the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

So, if you call `clock()` more often than the resolution, you are out of luck.

For profiling/benchmarking, you should --if possible-- use one of the performance clocks that are available on modern hardware. The prime candidates are probably

- The [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer)
- The [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter)

Edit: The question now references `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, which is Linux' way of exposing the TSC.

If any (or both) are available depends on the hardware in is also operating system specific.

Comment: I assumed one processor click would be for example the time it would take to execute the assembly instruction "inc EAX," but from what you indicate in the above I take it it's not that easy? And how would you suggest I could check whether TSC is available through my clock_gettime() with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID?

Comment: On modern CISC processor it can take many "processor click's" to execute something like inc EAX, and it can do many inc EAX instructions in parallel, so depending what else is going on the results will vary every time you run it.

Comment: @lash: [`clock_getcpuclockid(pid, CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_getcpuclockid.3.html) returns nonzero when the clock is available. I'm also not so sure if a tick counter would actually be useful in modern multicore environments. The Linux manpage even warns that in multi-CPU environments, the clock value might be bogus. Also, modern (and especially multi-core) CPUs do out-of order scheduling and have dynamic instruction delay so *`inc %eax` takes a tick* isn't really valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After googling a little bit I can see that clock() function can be used as a standard mechanism to find the tome taken for execution , but be aware that the time will be varying at different time depending upon the load of your processor,
You can just use the below code for calculation

```
clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();
/* here, do your time-consuming job */
end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```